# Background image disappears after selecting a link with same background

Tags: html, css

When I click on a link on a form that will take a user to a page with the same background image, it does not load.

The form is a standard log in with password reset and create new account links. All three share pretty similar HTML code and the background image is loaded under the body and shared amongst all three htmls. I'm unsure if this falls under any other question answered or if I am blatantly missing something

Above is the HTML that is the same for both passwordreset.html and newaccount.html
The only difference is that the other two both share a "back to login" link.

I'd just expected the image would act as a sort of constant between each HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>'Login Form'</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loginbox">
        <i class="fas fa-user fa-7x"></i>
        <h1>Login Here</h1>
        <form>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
            <a href="passwordreset.html">Forgot your Password?</a><br>
            <a href="newaccount.html">Create an account</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

=================================================

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>'Create New Account'</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loginbox newaccount">
        <i class="fas fa-user fa-7x"></i>
        <h1>Create New Account</h1>
        <form>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username">
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Create">
            <a href="form.html">Back to login screen</a><br>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

=================================================

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>'Reset Password'</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="loginbox passwordreset">
    <i class="fas fa-user fa-7x"></i>
    <h1>Password Reset</h1>
    <form>
        <p>Username</p>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username">
        <p>Email</p>
        <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Reset">
        <a href="form.html">Back to login screen</a><br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>


=================================================
CSS
=================================================


 body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background: url("images/travel.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
        background-size: cover;
      }
```

Comment: are you sure you added a link to your style on all your pages and nothing is overwriting the background style in the other pages? it will be helpful if you share all your code

Comment: Sounds like a path issue.

Comment: @MoneerKamal I included all the HTML code for this particular problem (and relevant CSS) there shouldn't be any other CSS code that overwhelms the body element?

Comment: @Paulie_D Are you referring to the path of loading the image or? (sorry if i should know, i'm still new ha)

Comment: Discovered the Issue, it was a path issue. I didn't suspect it because all the style loaded except for the background image. Cheers guys!

Comment: I'm assuming the path issue pertained to the different href's for your stylesheets. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">` VS `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheet/stylesheet.css">`